# PHP - Rendering dynamic web page through web browser

Tags: php, dynamic, web

I am new to php and programming,, I have been following a tutorial but I've ran into a problem when trying to display the products onto a web page, This is the code am testing

```
<?php 

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
    $id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']); 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
    $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); 
    if ($productCount > 0) {

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $price = $row["price"];
             $details = $row["details"];
             $category = $row["category"];
             $subcategory = $row["subcategory"];
             $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
         }

    } else {
        echo "That item does not exist.";
        exit();
    }

} else {
    echo "Data to render this page is missing.";
    exit();
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

When I try to view the page through my browser I get the message "Data to render this page is missing"

I understand that it''s something to do with

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
```

And am assuming maybe it's something to do with the 'id' But I cant work out how to fix it. Any pointers and help would be appreciated, sorry if this seems basic but like I said I am new and cant work this problem out. I've been trying all day

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see $_GET it's looking for a parameter in the URL. So:

```
http://localhost/yourphpscript.php?id=123
```

...is what it's expecting. Some ID must be defined in the URL.

Comment: Thanks, am not sure how to define the URL

Comment: Am going to try and work out how to do this, If I get stuck I will ask for further help :)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, `$_GET['id']` isn't set. If your link was something like `http://www.example.com/index.php?id=32`, it would be set.

Second, do not use GET/POST variables in queries without sanitising them!

And third, don't use mysql_query in the first place, but PDO or mysqli instead

Comment: Ok thank you, am not sure how to set the url, but am going to look into it. I thought the code I had would already have set it. Thanks for those points. Why do you say not to use mysql_query ?

Comment: it's been deprecated and it will be removed from the future PHP versions, so it will save you from trouble if you stop using it now

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code:

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['id'])){ //Someone submitted a form or just prepended parameter to link
      include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; //Include script with mysql connection
      $id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']); //Sanitize input - remove everything besides numbers
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1"); //Execute query. Only 1 product because of LIMIT 1
      if (mysql_num_rows($result)==1){ //If the product is found
         $product = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ; //Take the product
         foreach ($product as $property => $value){ //Go through each property of product
           echo "<div> {$property} : {$value} </div>" ;
         }
      }
    } else {?>
      <form method="get" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="id" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit product ID"/>
      </form>
<?php    
}
    ?>
```

Just ask if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, I don't think it would be good for me to use that code, as I have already set all the variables etc on other pages, and would probably have to change them all, thank you though, this gives me some insight into how to perform an operation in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

learn to track your id. sanitize and check the url sending the id for correct value passed and again in the begining check the value as in

```
                     <?php
                    echo $_GET['id'];
                      ?>
```

use this to know what it is your id value